# Search and replace multiple files

Tags: regular-expression, search

I have several files where I want to change a word in several files from oldWord to newWord.

Please note I want to do this with the new cpo feature. I also would like to do this in one command line chain, rather than one command at a time.

Should this command do it? Or is there a better way do this in VIM?

```
:set hidden | :vimgrep oldWord ./gulp-tasks/*.s | :cdo s/oldWord/newWord/g | :set wall  ?
```

Comment: That answer is outdated, there is a way to do this with the new quick fix window and cpo command. Also, I want to do this with chained commands in one line rather than one at a time.

Comment: that answer is not out of date. The first answer provides an `:argdo`/`:bufdo` method, the second `:cdo` method, and the 3rd uses the tried and true unix shell method. All of which are valid have there own pro's and con's. I am not aware of a `:cpo` command. I imagine you are looking for `:cdo` / `:cfdo`. See `:h cdo`.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you meant something like this

```
:set hidden
:vimgrep /foo/ dir/*.s
:cfdo %s/foo/bar/g | w
```

All in one line:

```
:set hidden | vimgrep/foo/ dir/*.s | cfdo %s/foo/bar/g | w
```

Related Vimcasts episode: [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/)

For more help see:

```
:h :vimgrep
:h :cfdo
:h 'hidden'
```